# How To Check 1 Table Columns in SQL Where Condition Operational Operator (> or <)

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Format

```
tid,name,num1,num2
1,abc,10,9
2,xyz,15,15
```

Result

```
1,abc,10,9
```

SQL Like

```
select field1,field2,field3 from table1 where field1 > field2
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. We know things - but it's not very clear what your actual question is. Could you give more details? Wher'y the table name?

Comment: Thank You For Support, actually i want to check where condition in sql between two table fields like "Select id,name,no,no1 from table where no>no1"

Comment: looks fine - where is the problem?

Comment: Not getting actual result like "1,abc,10,9" getting "2,xyz,15,15" that's wrong.

Comment: Give me some alternatives or hint regarding my sql query.

Comment: could you edit your question and show table definition ("show create table ...) also "no" is reserved word in mysql - should rename column id possible

Comment: ok i change my question but in question mention table formate is a example and in real db i used both field as a int also not used reserved keyword.

Comment: Giving an example we could easily run in our own DB would certainly be best.

Comment: ok i give my actual table with data but how i send sql script?

Comment: Just edit your question  to give ddl of table - inserts are easy...

Comment: Thank You so much, actually in bellow give answer through solve my problem. thank you support team.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the data type used in the table for those 2 columns are both varchar.

So you're not comparing numbers.
The number 10 is bigger than 9, but the string "10" is not bigger than "9".

You could alter the table and change them to a number type.

Or in the WHERE clause cast them to a number type before comparing them.

For example :

```
select * 
from table1 
where cast(field1 as SIGNED) > cast(field2 as SIGNED)
```

An example where the table types are altered

```
drop table if exists table1;
create table table1 (id int, name varchar(30), field1 varchar(8), field2 varchar(8));
insert into table1 (id,name,field1,field2) values
(1,'abc',10,9),
(2,'xyz',15,15);

select * 
from table1
where field1 <= field2;

alter table table1 
modify field1 INT SIGNED,
modify field2 INT SIGNED;

select * 
from table1
where field1 > field2;
```

Comment: i try and change data type in int but not getting actual output.

Comment: Good to hear :)  Anyway, you should change the types in the table. It'll save you from troubles like this, and it makes the table more efficient.